# Which version of Flash Builder do I need?

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

There is [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821969/which-version-of-flex-builder-do-i-need) but I think it was answered when Flash Builder was still Flex Builder.

I need to buy Flash Builder and really the Adobe site is not clear about the different versions. I need to know what is the difference between the standard and the premium editions. Is there a lack of components in the standard? Is there anything that I won´t be able to compile in standard or the differences are just in terms of the IDE functionality?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main differences between Standard and Premium versions are:

- Premium version has possibility to create and run unit tests within IDE.
- Premium version has profiler.
- Premium version has Network Monitor (to see requests and responses).
- Premium version has advanced Data wizards (to generate code by WSDL or to generate server side BlazeDS/LCDS code by DB).
- Premium version has possibility to operate with automation libraries.

All the other standard libraries, including data visualization (charts and ADG), are free and open-sourced and available in SDK since (if I not mistaken) 3.2 SDK version.

So if you need:

- Code editing.
- Debugger.
- Design view.
- Refactoring.
- Compiling (including AIR).
- SDK features and libraries.
- Multi SDK features.

In this case Standard version is enough.

You can see link to the compare matrix which hasn't all the features listed in @ www.Flextras.com comment :)

Comment: The "Pro" version is formally called "Premium".  I'll also add this link: http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder/matrix.html It does not call out unit testing, Data Wizards, or automation libraries as premium only features [but doesn't list them individually at all]