# Differences between Adoble Flash Builder 4.7 standard and premium

Tags: android, flash, apache-flex, adobe, builder

Does anyone know what exactly are the differences between Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 Standard and premium features?

In particular, I need enough of Flash Builder to be able to start with an existing flex project, build it and package it as Android and iOS targets.

Is this available in the Standard version or do I need the premium one to get mobile packaging?

EDIT: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081598/which-version-of-flash-builder-do-i-need) is the most similar question I found, but unfortunately it doesn't address the feature of mobile target packaging

Comment: If you only want to build your project without editing the code, you might want to save yourself 500$ and use the command line compiler, the ANT tasks (both of which come with the Flex SDK) or a build tool (like FlexMojos or GradleFx).

Comment: Thanks RIAstar. We've tried that and couldn't get the toolchain to work. Under normal circumstances we would continue at it until it's out the door, but this time around we're under time pressure and it makes more sense for us to just get the tool and move on to more important matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Adobe's Flash Builder FAQ](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-builder/faq.html) which has more information

> ```
>  What are the editions of Flash Builder 4.7?
>
>     Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 Standard Edition: Flash Builder 4.7 is a professional-grade development tool for rapidly creating games and
> ```
>
> applications for the web and mobile devices using ActionScript and the
>   open source Flex framework. It includes support for intelligent
>   coding, interactive step-though debugging, and multiplatform
>   publishing workflows.
>
> ```
>     Adobe Flash Builder 4.7 Premium Edition: This edition has all the great features that Standard offers plus professional testing
> ```
>
> tools, including profilers, network monitoring, unit testing support,
>   and command-line build support.
>
> ```
>  Why use Flash Builder Premium Edition over Flash Builder Standard Edition?
>
>     Flash Builder 4.7 Premium adds professional testing tools, including profilers, network monitoring, an automated testing
> ```
>
> framework, integration with Flex unit testing, and command-line build
>   support.

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I missed the faq. From reading it, it makes me reasonably comfortable that the standard edition will have the mobile target options we need.

Comment: @JulianCerruti Yes, you can create mobile projects / APKs for android and IPA for iOS using Flash Builder Standard.  [It should also support Blackberry Playbook; but I'm not sure if that is built in to Flash Builder 4.7 or if you have to download an additional plugin from BlackBerry]

Comment: Thank you @Reboog711, that is exactly what I wanted to know